# InvalidProjectFileException loading Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, project

I am attempting to load a Windows UWP project using the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` class using the following code:

```
Project coreVisualStudioProject = new Project(fileName);
```

The UWP project was created through Visual Studio by selecting File->New->Project..., selecting the Blank App (Universal windows), and clicking the OK button to create the app.

For reference, I have included the entire .csproj here:

http://pastebin.com/jyFXdzTr

The constructor throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)" that evaluates to "10.0.10240.0" instead of a number, in condition "'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' == 'UAP' And '$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)' != '' And '$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)' > '10.0.10587.0'".  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets
```

Has anyone experienced this problem before? I'm a little lost where to go from here given it's a standard UWP project, and a basic Project constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: A numeric comparison was attempted on

This exception is caused by some numeric comparison conditions defined in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets`

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.Targets
```

This is a known issue logged in our system. The related team is investigating it and updating the status in here: [Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets causes build failures](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/778)

Comment: As far as I understand using the `Microsoft.Build` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/) instead of the framework reference should fix the issue. At least it did fix a similar issue for me (The attribute "Visible" in element <Content> is unrecognized.).